# Unable to fix pthread memory leak with valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, pthreads, valgrind

Trying to manage memory leaks when a pthread is canceled in the middle of a long task. This is the source code reproducing the issue:

```
volatile static int run = 1;

client_context_t *clone_client_context()
{
    client_context_t *cli_ctx = (client_context_t *) calloc(1, sizeof(client_context_t));
    if (cli_ctx == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return cli_ctx;
}

void free_client_context(void *arg)
{
    client_context_t *cli_ctx = (client_context_t *) arg;

    printf("Freeing client context\n");

    if (cli_ctx)
        free(cli_ctx);
}

void *pthread_worker(void *data)
{
    int rc;
    client_context_t *cli_ctx = (client_context_t *) data;
    pthread_cleanup_push(free_client_context, cli_ctx);

    printf("Doing unuseful job for 10 seconds\n");
    sleep(10);

    printf("Freeing pthread_worker resources\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void run_worker_thread()
{
    client_context_t *cli_ctx = clone_client_context();
    if (cli_ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Problems cloning client context\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Running worker thread...\n");

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    pthread_create(&cli_ctx->pth_id, &attr, pthread_worker, cli_ctx);
    pthread_join(cli_ctx->pth_id, 0);
}

static void exit_handler(int signal)
{
    if ((signal != SIGINT) && (signal != SIGTERM))
        return;
    run = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Setup signals
    signal(SIGTERM, exit_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, exit_handler);

    run_worker_thread();

    while(run) {
        pause();
        printf("Stopping\n");
    }
}
```

If I wait 10 seconds until the pthread finishes, all resources are freed properly, and no leak is found:

```
==1136951== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1136951==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1136951==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 3,142 bytes allocated
==1136951== 
==1136951== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1136951== 
==1136951== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

However, whenever I kill the main process with Ctrl+C before waiting 10 seconds, the pthread is leaking memory.

```
==1137140== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1137140==     in use at exit: 408 bytes in 2 blocks
==1137140==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 1,432 bytes allocated
==1137140== 
==1137140== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==1137140==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1137140==    by 0x109363: clone_client_context (test.c:7)
==1137140==    by 0x1094B5: run_worker_thread (test.c:41)
==1137140==    by 0x1095C5: main (test.c:72)
==1137140== 
==1137140== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==1137140==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1137140==    by 0x40149CA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==1137140==    by 0x40149CA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==1137140==    by 0x4868322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==1137140==    by 0x4868322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==1137140==    by 0x109515: run_worker_thread (test.c:53)
==1137140==    by 0x1095C5: main (test.c:72)
==1137140== 
==1137140== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1137140==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1137140==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1137140==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==1137140==    still reachable: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==1137140==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1137140== 
==1137140== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As far as I understand, free_client_context function (i.e., pthread_cleanup_push callback) should be called before destroying the thread. But it is not called. So, I don't undestand the use of "pthread_cleanup_push" and "pthread_cleanup_pop".

Could you please explain how this works and what should be the proper way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't join detached threads (that's what detached means), so you should be getting an error return from `pthread_join()` in your `run_worker_thread()` function.  Nominally, you should call `pthread_attr_destroy()` before returning from that function.  Neither of these minor issues should affect the main problem you're facing, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to manage memory leaks when a pthread is canceled in the middle of a long task. This is the source code reproducing the issue:

On the contrary, the code presented does not reproduce a thread cancellation.  From the perspective of the pthreads docs, "cancellation" means specifically the effect of `pthread_cancel()`, which is never called in your example program.

> As far as I understand, free_client_context function (i.e.,
> pthread_cleanup_push callback) should be called before destroying the
> thread.

Not exactly. A cleanup handler registered via [`pthread_cleanup_push()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cleanup_push.html) is executed in (only) three cases:

1. The thread that registered it responds to a cancellation while the handler is still on its handler stack.
2. The thread that registered it terminates by calling `pthread_exit()` while the handler is still on its handler stack.<sup>*</sup>
3. The thread that registered it calls `pthread_cleanup_pop()` with a nonzero argument while the handler is at the top of its handler stack.

None of those cases is exercised when you terminate your program by sending it a `SIGINT`.  The program handles that signal in a way that causes the main thread to exit normally.  When the main thread terminates normally, all of the other threads in the process are terminated abruptly (not canceled).  As a result, your cleanup handler is not called.

> So, I don't undestand the use of "pthread_cleanup_push" and "pthread_cleanup_pop".

You seem to understand the programming paradigm well enough.  What you don't understand appears to be the use cases the facility is intended to serve.  Abrupt termination at process exit is not one of them, and that makes a fair amount of sense because all process-owned resources, including allocated memory, are released by the system when the owning process terminates.

> Could you please explain how this works and what should be the proper way to fix this issue?

What issue?  The process terminates.  All memory it allocated is freed (albeit not before Valgrind notices that it is not *explicitly* freed).

You could consider having the signal handler genuinely cancel the detached thread, but that probably just gets you a race, as the thread could still be terminated as a result of the main thread terminating before it has a chance to run its cleanup handlers.

If you want to be sure that all threads clean up, then you should ensure a clean shutdown of all threads.

---

<sup>*</sup>But *not* when the thread terminates by returning from the top-level call to its thread function.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and detailed explanation, it was very helpful.